# Kreem Beej Mantra Sadhana

Tags: tantra, kali, sadhana

What is Kreem Beej Mantra Sadhana, can it be used for the recovery of a person. I want to know everything about the mantra, the pros and cons of it, and whether I have to offer any puja to Kali? If yes, I'd like to know the full procedure. I'd like to know if I really need a guru for this purpose. What if I do this particular type of sadhana without any guru?

Comment: Welcome to HSE! As per this [edit revision](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/revisions/45277/2), looks like you wanted to delete this question, but was not able to. Visit [this help section](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question) to learn when and how to delete an answer.

Answer (score -1):

First of all everyone has to go through the process called death. Sooner or later everyone dies , you can keep chanting mantra but it may or may not have effect. However it may make the suffering less.
Devi demands determination, sacrifice and faith (Shraddha) ... Devote your life to it ... use any mantra of mother Goddess...but those 3 things are essential ...how you treat women in your life also become important... essentially she will take possession of everything you have... she will do what is best for you ... if are ok then go ahead and have a wonderful relationship...( you can use Gayatri mantra as well or worship all through Durga shaptashati)

Comment: @PranjalBasak Sacrifice means all kinds of sacrifice...

Comment: @PranjalBasak Accept the anger and the disaster if that happens but it is least likely

Comment: Hi, Welcome to HSE!! Please visit [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/17833) , and have an enriching journey in here.

Comment: I have been asked to give citations ... if you don’t believe me why even care to run such stupid forums which has no religious sense ???